# Android lollipop write to sdcard from native code c++

Tags: android, c++, android-5.0-lollipop, sd-card, fdopen

I have android application which uses a lot of c++ native code. Application needs to work with files located on sdcard(read, create, append). But Kitkat+ denied writing to sdcard for 3rd party applications. Android 5 introduced new API which allows that again.

[How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop)

All examples and documentation what I found are mostly for Java side. Examples for native code don't exist or are very unclear. So I want ask few questions.

The link above contains valuable example how to get DocumentFile which can return ParcelFileDescriptor. From this object I am able to receive native file descriptor - ParcelFileDescriptor.getFd(). It's integer which I am sending to c++ code through jni.

In c++ I am opening file with fdopen(fd).

My questions are :

1. Is fdopen function correct way how to open the file with new api? Or the DocumentFile already opens the file and I should only use fd in further operations.
2. It's enough to close the file descriptor inside native code with fclose? or should I close it on java side with ParcelFileDescriptor.detachFd(). Or both.

Thank you

EDIT : I getFD and detachFD works. But I never found answer how to correctly replace ftruncate, which needs write access too, and I did not found ftruncate version which takes file descriptor like a input

Answer (score 0):

1) yes, use file descriptors and fdopen
2)

1. Open the `ParcelFileDescriptor`.
2. getFd().
3. Pass the Fd to native code.
4. Close the `ParcelFileDescriptor`. (this is closing your java reference)

Fd is just an `int` representing a linux id for a file.  In native:

1. Fdopen
2. Do stuff
3. Fclose (note this is closing your native file pointer)

The two closes are doing different things.

Note: You still need the SAF permission for the file or a higher root.

Comment: how can I fix the same issue for ftruncate? There is no version of ftruncate what accepts file descriptor

Comment: The only way would be to use the cache as swap space and transfer using SAF.  I initially had to do that with the MTP methods since they didn't have FD, either.  Submit a bug report, in three years they'll fix it, they did for MTP.   SAF was one of the most ill conceived and executed frameworks I have ever seen.  They broke half their code and just plain didn't care for years.

Comment: Over night I wrote my own ftruncate version using fseek and copying data from one file to another. But...my app is emulator which needs performance and emulated ftruncate is slow. When I am talking about it, jumping to java for file descriptor is very slow too.

Answer (score -1):

Try Below Links:

Android - writing/saving files from native code only:
[Android - writing/saving files from native code only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294487/android-writing-saving-files-from-native-code-only)

Android NDK Write File:
[Android NDK Write File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731314/android-ndk-write-file)

File Operations in Android NDK:
[File Operations in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992953/file-operations-in-android-ndk)

Comment: Hi, thank you. These link are very useful. But unfortunately are not actual if the filesystem is protected with SAF https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: Currently I use ParcelFileDescriptor.detachFd() and I send it to native code. File is then closed with fclose() function. But I am getting this warning: W/ParcelFileDescriptor﹕ Peer expected signal when closed; unable to deliver after detach....